# AutoHotkey ControlSetText

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to change the contents of a window. I have code that ends as follow:

```
...
ControlFocus, SysListView321, A
ControlGet, CtrlText, List,, SysListView321, A
;  MsgBox %CtrlText% ; This shows the correct contents, as expected
```

I now want to change the contents of the above. Using Window Spy, I've determined that:

```
ClassNN = SysListView321
Text = List1
```

I've tried the following (one at a time):

```
ControlSetText, SysListView321, New Text Here, A
ControlSetText, List1, New Text Here, A
```

neither of which have any effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using a ListView. You cannot ControlSetText with a ListView... you must select a Row that is already present, or add the Row and then select it. In fact, ListViews have an entire category of functions that belong purely to them. THey are all prefixed with LV_. You're looking for LV_Add() or LV_Modify().